# Appending and Prepending Text to All Selected Cells

Tags: excel

The purpose of this code is apply a function to each selected cell.  This works on contiguous and non-contiguous selections.

### function assignText(value, prepend)

Returns a closure that encapsulates the original parameter values and a callback function which takes a single cell as a parameter.  This closure is then passed into `eachSelectedCell(callback)`.

Specifications:

- Cells with formulas are ignored
- Only one instance of the value is allowed
- Address is loaded for future stack tracing

### async function eachSelectedCell(callback)

Iterates over each cell of each area of the ActiveSheet's selection, passing the cell into the callback function.

[image: Gif Demo]

```
$("#run").click(() => tryCatch(run));

async function run() {
  /** Test Prepend Value */
  await eachSelectedCell(assignText("<-goodbye", false));

  /** Test Append Value */
  await eachSelectedCell(assignText("hello->", true));
}

function assignText(value, prepend) {
  this.prepend = prepend;
  this.value = value;
  const that = this;
  return async function(cell) {
    cell.load(["values", "address", "formulas"]);
    await cell.context.sync();

    if (!cell.formulas[0][0].toString().startsWith("=")) {
      let value = cell.values.toString();

      if (value.includes(that.value)) 
        value = value.replaceAll(RegExp(that.value, "g"), "");

      if (that.prepend)
        cell.values = that.value + value;
      else 
        cell.values = value + that.value;
    }
  };
}

async function eachSelectedCell(callback) {
  const context = new Excel.RequestContext();
  const cells = [];
  const target = context.workbook.getSelectedRanges();
  context.trackedObjects.add(target);
  const areas = target.areas.load(["areas", "address"]);
  await context.sync();

  for (let n = 0; n < areas.items.length; n++) {
    const area = areas.items[n];
    area.load(["rowCount", "columnCount", "address"]);
    await context.sync();
    for (let i = 0; i < area.rowCount; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < area.columnCount; j++) {
        let cell = area.getCell(i, j);
        context.trackedObjects.add(cell);
        await callback(cell);
        cell.untrack();
      }
    }
  }

  target.untrack();
  await context.sync();
}
```

As is often the case on CR, I'm looking for ways to improve the performance.